# retryWhen from different threads

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

I have a situation with RxJava that I can't quite understand. I had this observable setting that worked pretty well.

```
Observable.create(subscriber -> makeWebCall())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .observeOn(AndroidScheduler.newThread())
    .retryWhen(observable ->
                observable.flatMap(throwable -> {
                    if (throwable instanceof UserRecoverableException) {
                        return Observable.from(someUIFlowObservable());
                    }
                    return Observable.error(throwable);
                }))
    .subscribe(response -> response.doSomething(), t -> throwError(t));
```

So I made a web call and if I got a recoverable exception, I retried the call after making some changes in the UI thread.

But of course, this was all taking place as a result of some UI interaction i.e. button click. And there was also an observable chain there, so I modified that chain to also include this call, like so:

```
Rx.click(someButton)
    .switchMap(o -> getSomeStringPreferenceObservable())
    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .switchMap(str -> Observable.create(subscriber - >makeWebCall()))
    .observeOn(AndroidScheduler.mainThread())
    .retryWhen(observable ->
                observable.flatMap(throwable -> {
                    if (throwable instanceof UserRecoverableException) {
                        return Observable.from(someUIFlowObservable());
                    }
                    return Observable.error(throwable);
                }))
    .subscribe(response -> response.doSomething(), t -> throwError(t));
```

Now, the `retryWhen` does not work. As should be pretty obvious, the big difference between the two is the `subscribeOn` method. But I'm not sure I understand what is going on and what I can do to get the desired outcome.

Comment: Does the retryWhen receive the error? I'd check events with `doOnNext` to see where it disappears.

Comment: It does receive the error, UI updates, does it's thing, returns a value but then nothing. I'll try the `doOnNext` for debugging.

Comment: what is someUIFlowObservable() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it works, you just have to click again that button.

The reason is that retryWhen resubscribes the whole chain but the  Rx.click(someButton) has not emitted anything new (after the re-subscription) so the rest will not be processed.

If the `UserRecoverableException` is emitted by `makeWebCall()` then move the retry into that observable:

```
.switchMap(str -> Observable.create(subscriber - > makeWebCall())
    .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .retryWhen(observable -> observable.flatMap(throwable -> {
      if (throwable instanceof UserRecoverableException) {
        return Observable.from(someUIFlowObservable())
            .subscribeOn(mainThread());
      }
      return Observable.error(throwable);
    }))
)
```

Ps: There is no `AndroidScheduler.newThread()` in newer RxAndroid :)

Ps 2: You don't need to call `.subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` if you run the observable from an Activity or Fragment.

Comment: So that solves part of the issue but not all of it. The retryWhen needs be observed on the main thread, not a new thread. If I observe the retry on the main thread, it behaves correctly and the request is retried. However, the retry happens on the main thread too leading to a network call on main thread exception. The thread needs to somehow be changed between the retryWhen call and the actual retry.

Comment: @SaadFarooq You can create the observable in the main thread - see updated code.